# How to do this tricky subscraction in Numpy:

Tags: python, numpy

I look for how this operation would be done in Numpy with one lile / one operator. 
Normal numpy substraction between 1d vector and a matrix would work like that:

```
weights = np.array([[2,3,0], [10,11,12], [1,2,4] , [10,11,12]], dtype = np.float)


inputs = np.array([1,2,3] , dtype = np.float)

print(inputs  - weights)
```

Result is :

```
[[-1. -1.  3.]
 [-9. -9. -9.]
 [ 0.  0. -1.]
 [-9. -9. -9.]]
```

Contain the substraction from inputs  -weights[0] ,  inputs  -weights[1]

I look for a way to do this with one operator for 2d array like :

```
inputs = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[7,8,9],[4,5,4]] , dtype = np.float)

weights = np.array([[2,3,0], [10,11,12], [1,2,4] , [10,11,12]], dtype = np.float)

#inputs  - weights would be elementwise substraction

output = [i - weights for i in inputs] 
print(output)
```

But that creates a loop in Python, how to do that properly with numpy arrays?

Comment: no, this will do elementwise, I guess i v properly explained how do i want to sub. It will be 3d tensor as output

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: its solved by Mark Meyer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expand inputs with `np.expand_dims(inputs, axis=1)` giving it a shape of `(4, 1, 3)` so when you broadcast the subtraction it will work the way you want:

```
import numpy as np

inputs =  np.array([[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [7,8,9], [4,5,4]] , dtype = np.float)
weights = np.array([[2,3,0], [10,11,12], [1,2,4], [10,11,12]], dtype = np.float)


np.expand_dims(inputs, axis=1) - weights
```

**result**

```
array([[[-1., -1.,  3.],
        [-9., -9., -9.],
        [ 0.,  0., -1.],
        [-9., -9., -9.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  4.],
        [-8., -8., -8.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  0.],
        [-8., -8., -8.]],

       [[ 5.,  5.,  9.],
        [-3., -3., -3.],
        [ 6.,  6.,  5.],
        [-3., -3., -3.]],

       [[ 2.,  2.,  4.],
        [-6., -6., -8.],
        [ 3.,  3.,  0.],
        [-6., -6., -8.]]])
```

Comment: wow thanks, thats clever :D. also inputs = inputs.reshape(-1,1,3) works, thanks

Comment: wait, does expand creates new array or its reference to the same?

Comment: can you please say how to do the same to the summ then :
        for input_index , winner_index in enumerate(winners):
            self.weights_t [winner_index] += lr*(batch[input_index][0] - self.weights_t [winner_index] )
with one line pls?